# Syslog-ng Time Format & Time Zone

Tags: syslog-ng

I'm currently using a fairly old version of `syslog-ng`, 2.1.4, and yes I know I need to update it as soon as possible, but for now I need help on modifying the date/time format and time zone.

Currently everything comes into syslog-ng and gets dumped to a local directory or sent to another device via UDP. The normal log format is:

```
May  1 00:00:08 hostname.example.com Here is the full message
```

For one device I'm forwarding the logs to, they want all time formats to be in UTC and also instead of "May  1", they want it to be "May 01".

```
destination d_test {
    udp("remote_host.domain.com" port(514) spoof_source(yes) time_zone("UTC")); };
```

When I do this, I get the following error and the log time doesn't change to the receiving host.

> Bogus timezone spec, must be in the format [+-]HH:MM, offset must be
>   less than 24:00; value='UTC'

Is there another way to modify this? As far as the 2 symbol date formats, I've tried a few template options but haven't been able to get the initial portion to change yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `+04:00` (or whatever your time shift would be to get to UTC) instead of `UTC` for the time zone.

I don't know of any way to easily just change the day of the month to two digits with syslog-ng, but you can get an ISO 8601 compatible standard timestamp (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+-ZONE) by using `ISODATE` instead of `DATE`. Those can be easier to parse, which may or may not help you depending on your situation.

You could do something with `awk`, `sed`, or `perl` to go through log files and change the datestamp after the fact, but that seems like it may cause other problems.

Comment: Thanks @dogontouch. The offset of +00:00 worked good for sending via UTC time.

Comment: You can also use "GMT" instead of "+00:00". The list of valid timezone names is in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. See the documentation for `time-zone()`: https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.37/administration-guide/46#kanchor2885